# Get file content of change using Gerrit API

Tags: git, gerrit

Im using the Gerrit API (/changes/64/revisions/current/files/my_file/content) to access file content. Is there any way to get the "base" content of this file, the content which the change was based on?

I've tried using

/changes/64/revisions/0/files/my_file/content

but with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a gitweb or any other repo browser enabled in Gerrit?

Comment: I'm running the Gerrit web interface and Gitblit

Comment: Is Gitblit exposing Gerrit's repos or is Gerrit replicating to Gitblit. I think it's possible to get raw files from Gitblit, so you might be able to browse to the refspec (see the fetch command) and retrieve the file from gitblit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the [get-diff](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-diff) API, from there you can derive the original file content

Comment: I ended up using the [get-patch](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#get-patch) API and then using a patch tool in reverse mode to create my base version.

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit should have native support to this...

But here is how you can trick it to return you any file at any given {tag,branch,commit} in python:

```py
# pip install python-gerrit-api
from gerrit import GerritClient
import base64

client = GerritClient(
    base_url=url,
    username=username,
    password=password
)
# `project` is project name
# `version` is tag/branch/commit
# `path` is path to a file, relative to project root
b64 = client.gitiles.gerrit.get(client.gitiles.endpoint+ f"/{project}/+/{version}/{path}", params={"format": "TEXT"})
content = base64.b64decode(b64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'GET /projects/{project-name}/commits/{commit-id}/files/{file-id}/content'

see:
https://gerrit.sio2project.mimuw.edu.pl/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#get-content-from-commit